# IA32 assembly language stack trace

Tags: c, stack, trace, x86

I have been struggling with an IA32 assembly language question I received during a university lab. I can't quite firgure out how to go about it, and was wondering if anyone here could give me a hand.

The question says: Draw the runtime stack at the following points during execution, starting from the parameter passed to fact_do and ending with the top of the stack. In each case label each 4 byte memory location and indicate the contents when known. Show where %ebp and %esp point to.

The point I can't quite draw the stack trace for is: "Just before the leave instruction in fact_do (leave is equivalent to movl %ebp, %esp followed by popl %ebp)."

I think what is expected is something along the lines of:

```
 _____________
|             |  <- %ebp
| .           |
| .           |
| .           |
|_____________|
|_5___________|
|_Rtn_Address_|  <- %esp
```

The following is the code that is to be traced:

```
    .file    "fact.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string    "%d! = %d\n"        #string is initialized
    .text
.globl main
    .type    main, @function
main:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $5, (%esp)        #(%esp) <- 5         [(%esp) = n]
    call    fact_do
    movl    $.LC0, %edx    #set up print statement
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)        #8(%esp) <- %eax     [%eax = 120, return value of fact_do]
    movl    $5, 4(%esp)        #4(%esp) <- 5
    movl    %edx, (%esp)        #print statement location
    call    printf            #print output
    movl    $0, %eax        #%eax <- 0
    leave
    ret
    .size    main, .-main
.globl fact_do
    .type    fact_do, @function
fact_do:
    pushl    %ebp            #push %ebp onto stack
    movl    %esp, %ebp        #%ebp <- %esp
    subl    $16, %esp        #%esp <- %esp - 16
    movl    $1, -4(%ebp)        #-4(%ebp) <- 1        [-4(%ebp) = result]
.L4:
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax        #%eax <- -4(%ebp)
    imull    8(%ebp), %eax        #%eax <- %eax * 8(%ebp) [8(%ebp) = n]
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)        #-4(%ebp) <- %eax     [result <- result*n]
    subl    $1, 8(%ebp)        #8(%ebp)--           [n--]
    cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)        #8(%ebp) > 1 ?         [n > 1]
    jg    .L4                 #Repeat loop if 8(%ebp) > 1
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax        #%eax <- -4(%ebp)     [%eax <- 120, result]
    leave
    ret
    .size    fact_do, .-fact_do
    .ident    "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
Optimized:
    .file    "fact.c"
    .text
.globl fact_do
    .type    fact_do, @function
fact_do:
    pushl    %ebp            #push %ebp (for return)
    movl    %esp, %ebp           #%ebp <- %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx            #%edx <- 8(%ebp) [%edx = n]
    movl    $1, %eax                #%eax <- 1 [%eax = result]
.L2:
    imull    %edx, %eax           #%eax <- %edx * %eax [result <- n * result]
    subl    $1, %edx                #%edx-- [n--]
    cmpl    $1, %edx                #%edx > 1 ? [n > 1]
    jg    .L2                    #repeat if %edx > 1 [if n > 1]
    popl    %ebp                #%ebp <- top value on stack (for return)
    ret
    .size    fact_do, .-fact_do
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string    "%d! = %d\n"        #prepare string
    .text
.globl main
    .type    main, @function
main:
    pushl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $5, (%esp)            #%esp <- 5
    call    fact_do
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)            #8(%esp) <- %eax [%eax = result]
    movl    $5, 4(%esp)            #4(%esp) <- 5
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)            #set up print statement
    call    printf               #print
    movl    $0, %eax                #%eax <- 0
    leave
    ret
    .size    main, .-main
    .ident    "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Which translates to the following in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fact_do(int n);
int main(){
    printf("%d! = %d\n", 5, fact_do(5));
    return 0;
}

int fact_do(int n){
   int result = 1;
   do {
       result *= n;
       n = n-1;
   } while (n > 1);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: The sketch of the stack seems to be right for *after* the `leave` instruction, right before `ret`.

Comment: Seriously? Because that was a pretty big guess, haha

Comment: Well, I haven't really checked. But it certainly isn't *before* the `leave`, because `%esp` is already pointing at the return address.

Comment: Would the sketch also be accurate for just after the call to fact_do?

Comment: If it is correct after `leave`, it is correct before `pushl` at the start of the function, provided no stack variables of the calling function have been modified (which is the case here, as no pointers to local variables of the calling function were passed to `fact_do()`). However, your assignment may require the missing stack variables of both `main()` and `fact_do()` to be sketched explicitly.